# Proper verb to use with the noun help

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I would like to say "I thank you for all the help you have given with this item", but the word "given" doesn't sound right.  What other verb can I use here?

Comment: ‘Given’ is perfect.  Go ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word *give* is perfectly alright.

If you'd like to sound a bit more formal, however, alternatives include: *provide*, *offer* and *extend*.

Comment: "provided" is what I need.  It's not because I want to sound more formal, but because the "item" in question is something that doesn't sound right with the word "given".  (I didn't want to share what this item was.)

Comment: Hello, jl. ELU being a site aimed at linguists, answers should be backed up by supporting authoritative references. If you think that the answer is too obvious to need such, I would agree. But then the proper procedure is to close-vote (perhaps suggesting OP does some research themself, and the availability of ELL).